# How do I get only a defined amount of attributes of my Express API with a browser?

Tags: api, express, browser, localhost

Let me give an example: By accessing the following page we have access to all JSON code: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

But if I want I can retrieve just the first 6 elements of the JSON by accessing the following: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=6

I want to do this same thing with my Express code that I am accessing with `http://localhost:3100`

When I try `http://localhost:3100?_limit=6` it brings the entire JSON file, I don't understand why. How can I fix this? I want the browser to be able to limit the amount that it gets from the API.

Here is my Express code:

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const projects = [
  { project: "Challenges_jschallenger.com" },
  { project: "Using-Studio-Ghilis-API-With-JS-Only" },
  { project: "my-portfolio-next" },
  { project: "Youtube-Navbar-2021" },
  { project: "Mana-raWozonWebsite" },
  { project: "Movies-Website" },
  { project: "Add-Remove-Mark-and-Mark-off-With-ReactJS" },
  { project: "My-Portfolio" },
  { project: "Github_Explorer" },
  { project: "MestreALMO.github.io" },
  { project: "Tests-With-useState-useEffect-useRef" },
  { project: "Tic-Tac-Toe-React-in-JS" },
  { project: "ReactJS-with-TypeScript-Template" },
  { project: "Retractable-Accordion" },
];

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send(projects);
});

app.listen(3100);
```

Comment: Where in your server code do you think you use or even _access_ that query parameter? Your endpoint _always_ returns the whole array, because you've defined no logic to do otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the query from the express request. Also the correct way to respond with a json object would be to call the `json` method.

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const { limit } = req.query
  res.json(projects.slice(0, limit))
})
```

For it to work you would have to make the request to `http://localhost:3100/?limit=6`

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not know all of that.